# Calling Service's method multiple times holds single data instance

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I am using services for my AngularJS project and trying to call a service.method using a for loop, like this :

```
for( key in URLs) {
   Service.fetchXML(key); 
}
```

Service description:

```
[..]

fetchXML : function(resource) {

var prop = SomeVar[resource]; //SomeVar is declared within the service

$.get('xmlURL.xml?resource='+prop, function(data) {
  //adds data to the IndexedDB after properly parsing it. 
  console.log(resource)
  dbAdd();
})
```

Problem is when I try `resource` inside fetchXML() method; its set permanently, means if the loop runs for five times, only one instance of fetchXML() is created and console.log(resource) returns the same for all five iterations.

Please tell me what am I doing wrong here.

Comment: kindly share the service code please

Comment: try to fetch XML in array :)

Comment: isn't it obvious that the problem isn't in the code you've shown? Did you expect people here to have crystal balls to figure out what `fetchXML()` code does and why it is causing a problem? Ask incomplete questions and you get poor response, add proper detail and you will be amazed how fast you get feedback

Comment: @Ajaybeniwal added more details.

Comment: @charlietfl added more details.

Answer (score 0):

```
for( key in URLs) {
   Service.fetchXML(); 
}
```

Should be passing parameter to function since it is used as `resource` to create `prop`.

```
for( key in URLs) {
   Service.fetchXML(key); 
}
```

This should have been fairly easy to troubleshoot. First it would be apparent in the request url inspected in browser console/dev tools.

Also using some simple `degugger` or `console.log()` statements in function would have helped. Or setting breakpoint on the function and stepping through it to see variable values

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. You are right, I should have mentioned that ``key`` is already being passed in the function (its a typo). Secondly, I am using console.log() to see the values and also Logging XHR requests to see the outgoing requests. All indicate the same thing - same key value is being passed in all XML requests instead of different keys (as per the loop).

Comment: well can't see where keys come from or what's in `SomeVar` object either... can't help without more code. Try creating a demo that replicates problem in jsfiddle.net